# Modify blob representation field data with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geometry, arcgis-10.7, representation

I want to modify the data stored in the "Override" *blob* type field in ArcGIS 10.7 with ArcPy.
When I use the search cursor, it finds nothing:

```
data = row.getValue("Override")
if data:
   print("Gotcha!")

else:
   print("Nothing...")
```

I somewhere read that search cursors doesn't recognise these fields.

Is there a way to get the stored data, perhaps by modify the blob "geometry"?

Comment: Have you tried the data access cursors, e.g. `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`?  The non-`da` cursors are deprecated

Comment: I have ArcGIS 10.7 only, where there is no arcpy.da.SearchCursor() function, only arcpy.SearchCursor. It is not the professional one... :(

Comment: The "data access" versions are present in 10.1 onward regardless of license level: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm